# How to unset _none option inside field collection?

Tags: 7, entities

Normally, in a node form you'ld unset the `_none` option like so:

```
function MYMODULE_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    unset($form['field_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#options']['_none']);
}
```

Why doesn't this work in a field collection? I tried:

```
function MYMODULE_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $field_collection = $form['field_field_collection'][LANGUAGE_NONE];
    $delta = 0;
    $max_delta = $field_collection['#max_delta'];
    while ($delta <= $max_delta) {
        unset($field_collection[$delta]['field_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#options']['_none']);
        $delta++;
    }
}
```

In `dpm()` the option is unset and doesn't appear anymore. But on the screen it's still there... What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're modifying a local variable. You need

```
$field_collection = &$form['field_field_collection'][LANGUAGE_NONE];
```

or

```
unset($form['field_field_collection'][LANGUAGE_NONE][$delta]['field_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#options']['_none']);
```